# When a VM Template was last used (to create a VM)?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, powercli

I need to know when a VM Template was last used (to create a VM)?
As I am working on a project of segregating unused templates in my vSphere environment, I need to know that answer.

I tried
`Get-Template TemplateName | select *`
But is not giving me the required information, Any help here is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: You might be able to parse your vCenter logs to find when TemplateName was last cloned. That's not very practical but it's the only way I can think of.

Comment: That did work. The logs were present on "/var/log/vmware/output/vsphere_events_*.evt.out" I used a log data analytics tool, to pull the information on when that template was last "deployed on host".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs were present on "/var/log/vmware/output/vsphere_events_*.evt.out". I used a log data analytics tool, to pull the information on when a template was last "deployed on host", the aggregated result was the one I needed.

Thank you Mikael H for your insights.
Thank you Gerald Schneider for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve this information, it is not stored within the template.